# The way to speed up multiple ElseIf queries in VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement

I've been working on this code all day and have finally gotten everything to work perfectly. The only problem, is that the code does run pretty slow. Considering that it will be used on a workbook with thousands of rows I would like to change that. I am extremely new to vba so there is probably stuff in here that is wrong or seems like a bad shortcut. I think I added a couple of ways that could speed it up but i didnt know if anything else could be done.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CL_NC()

Dim lZeile  As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Gesamt")

For lZeile = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  
If InStr(.Range("D" & lZeile).Value, "Malaysia") > 0 And (InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "ISO 9001") > 0 Or InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "ISO 14001") > 0 Or InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "BS OHSAS 18001") > 0 Or InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "ISO 45001") > 0 Or InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "ISO 50001") > 0) Then
        .Range("G" & lZeile).Value = "Malaysia IMS CL"
ElseIf InStr(.Range("D" & lZeile).Value, "Malaysia") > 0 And InStr(.Range("C" & lZeile).Value, "IMS") > 0 Then
        .Range("G" & lZeile).Value = "Malaysia IMS NC"
ElseIf InStr(.Range("D" & lZeile).Value, "Malaysia") > 0 Then
        .Range("G" & lZeile).Value = "Malaysia " & .Range("C" & lZeile).Value & " NC"

ElseIf InStr(.Range("D" & lZeile).Value, "Indonesien") > 0 And (InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "ISO 9001") > 0 Or InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "ISO 14001") > 0 Or InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "BS OHSAS 18001") > 0 Or InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "ISO 45001") > 0 Or InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "ISO 50001") > 0) Then
        .Range("G" & lZeile).Value = "Indonesien IMS CL"
ElseIf InStr(.Range("D" & lZeile).Value, "Indonesien") > 0 And InStr(.Range("C" & lZeile).Value, "IMS") > 0 Then
        .Range("G" & lZeile).Value = "Indonesien IMS NC"
ElseIf InStr(.Range("D" & lZeile).Value, "Indonesien") > 0 Then
        .Range("G" & lZeile).Value = "Indonesien " & .Range("C" & lZeile).Value & " NC"


        
     Else
        .Range("G" & lZeile).Value = ""
     End If
  Next lZeile
End With

End Sub
```

This is how the table looks right now. Column G should show the VBA result.

[image]

@Damian: Dear Damian, your help here was really fantastic. But I am afraid, I need your assistance once again… I have some countries in the table (i.e. Bulgaria“) which obey to the same rules as Malaysia & Indonesia, but additionally they should also be marked as „Bulgaria Food CL“ when the entry in the column B = „ISO 22000“ (in this case the entry in column C is „Food“). Can it also be solved within this code? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Arrays are recommended when dealing with large amounts of data, they increase the process speed dramatically because you only interact with excel two times (one to read the range into the array and the other one to paste the array back to the sheet), instead of thousands of times like you do when looping through cells.

Comment: Thank you so much, dear Damian, for a swift reply. I am a really new in it. Could you kindly help me with "conversion" to array?

Comment: @Damian you're right, but I couldn't see how you'd use arrays in this context?

Comment: Give me 5, I think I can wrap your code inside the array with a cleaner way.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes maybe the answer I've posted give you some tips on how to use the array.

Comment: @Damian Thanks, I'm impressed!!

Comment: You don't want to go from 2 to the number of rows in the workbook. That's a huge waste. You want to go from 2 to the end of the `.UsedRange`.

Comment: @Tomalak the OP's code goes from 2 to the last row with data in column 1, `.UsedRange` could hold blank cells because they were previously used and not anymore (`.ClearContents`keeps the used rows `.Delete`deletes them from the `UsedRange`)

Comment: @Damian I see, thanks.

Comment: @Sam is your data filtered or is it to show the error?

Comment: @Damian it is filtered, in order to give a better overview :-)

Comment: @Sam that is weird... if the data is filtered when you want to paste the array it does stuff like that but... See that I only change the `arr(i, 7)` I don't change anything else so it's hard that this happen. Try my edited code (will unfilter before pasting the array back).

Comment: @Damian oh my God! You are absolutely right! It was filtered from the very beginning. If I set off the filter, it makes a wonder! Everything is perfect and so fast! Thank you so much!

Comment: @sam my last code on my answer does the unfilter for you for if you forget ;P remember to accept my answer if is good for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it all right, this should do the trick in seconds:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CL_NC()

    'Looks like your whole range is between A:G columns, so we insert that data
    'inside the array
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Gesamt")
        'Last row
        Dim i  As Long: i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'insert your data into the array
        Dim arr As Variant: arr = .Range("A1:G" & i).Value
        'Declare a Country variable
        Dim Country As String
        'Loop through row 2 to the last (inside the array
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
            'Check which country we have
            Select Case GetString(arr(i, 4))
                Case "Malaysia"
                    Country = "Malaysia"
                Case "Indonesien"
                    Country = "Indonesien"
                Case Else
                    arr(i, 7) = vbNullString
                    GoTo NextRow
            End Select
            
            'Check which ISO we have
            Select Case GetString(arr(i, 2))
                Case "ISO 9001", "ISO 14001", "BS OHSAS 18001", "ISO 45001", "ISO 50001"
                    Country = Country & " IMS CL"
                Case Else
                    If arr(i, 3) Like "*IMS*" Then
                        Country = Country & " IMS NC"
                    Else
                        Country = Country & " " & arr(i, 3) & " NC"
                    End If
            End Select
            arr(i, 7) = Country
NextRow:
        Next i
        .AutofilterMode = False
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:G" & i).Value = arr
    End With

End Sub
Private Function GetString(ByVal KeyValue As String) As String
    'Helper function to extract they key value for the strings
    'You can add as much as you need with Else If
    If KeyValue Like "*Malaysia*" Then
        GetString = "Malaysia"
    ElseIf KeyValue Like "*Indonesien*" Then
        GetString = "Indonesien"
    ElseIf KeyValue Like "*ISO 9001*" Then
        GetString = "ISO 9001"
    ElseIf KeyValue Like "*ISO 14001*" Then
        GetString = "ISO 14001"
    ElseIf KeyValue Like "*ISO 45001*" Then
        GetString = "ISO 45001"
    ElseIf KeyValue Like "*BS OHSAS 18001*" Then
        GetString = "BS OHSAS 18001"
    ElseIf KeyValue Like "*ISO 50001*" Then
        GetString = "ISO 50001"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, Damian!

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the following error message: ByRef argument type mismatch. The script stops at Select Case GetString(arr(i, 4))

Comment: @Sam my bad... copy the edited code, forgot to add `ByVal` on the `GetString`

Comment: @sam post a screenshot from the before and the after in your question editting it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64043091/edit) And delete the comment with all the data above.

Comment: Dear Damian, I'd like to accept this answer as a useful. How can I do it? I am clicking on the arrow, but only get the following message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @Sam below the arrow there is a check symbol, that's for accepting the answer

Comment: Done! Thank you so much! Not only for help, but also for patience!

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for "Malaysia" and "Indonesien" each time separately. I don't know how much difference this will make, but I'd have thought the below layout is at least easier to read/edit;

Firstly, `Dim strCountry as String` near the top.
Then inside the `For...Next` loop put;

```
'First check the country
If Instr(.Range("D" & LZeile).Value, "Malaysia") Then
    strCountry = "Malaysia "
ElseIf InStr(.Range("D" & lZeile).Value, "Indonesien") > 0 Then
    strCountry = "Indonesien "
Else 'If neither country is found
    strCountry = ""
    .Range("G" & lZeile).Value = ""
End If

If len(strCountry)>0 Then 'if one of the countries was found, then check other elements in column B
   If Instr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "ISO ") > 0 And _
        (InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "9001") > 0 Or _
        InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "14001") > 0 Or _
        InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "45001") > 0 Or _
        InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "50001") > 0) Or _
        InStr(.Range("B" & lZeile).Value, "BS OHSAS 18001") > 0  Then
            .Range("G" & lZeile).Value = strCountry & "IMS CL"
    ElseIf InStr(.Range("C" & lZeile).Value, "IMS") > 0 Then
            .Range("G" & lZeile).Value = strCountry & "IMS NC"
    Else
            .Range("G" & lZeile).Value = strCountry & .Range("C" & lZeile).Value & " NC"

    End If
End If
```

I know that appears more than yours - partly because it's formatted / indented differently - but by putting the 'Malaysia/Indonesia' check separate to the other statements you're lessening how many lines of code actually run. I'd noticed you'd basically copied a lot of those lines with only minor variation - one general goal is to only write any code line once, and make it re-usable for simplicity and speed.

For someone new to vba though, that's an excellent effort! And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with caching the Range objects you want to work with, the string values you are looking at, and nesting the `If` between a top-level check for the nation and a nested check for the ISO value:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CL_NC()
  Dim lZeile  As Long
  Dim ws As WorkSheet
  Dim B As Range, Bx As String
  Dim C As Range, Cx As String
  Dim D As Range, Dx As String
  Dim G As Range

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Gesamt")      
  Set B = ws.Range("B:B")
  Set C = ws.Range("C:C")
  Set D = ws.Range("D:D")
  Set G = ws.Range("G:G")

  For lZeile = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Bx = B.Cells(lZeile).Value
    Cx = C.Cells(lZeile).Value
    Dx = D.Cells(lZeile).Value
    If InStr(Dx, "Malaysia") > 0 Then
      If InStr(Bx, "ISO 9001") > 0 Or InStr(Bx, "ISO 14001") > 0 Or InStr(Bx, "BS OHSAS 18001") > 0 Or InStr(Bx, "ISO 45001") > 0 Or InStr(Bx, "ISO 50001") > 0 Then
        G.Cells(lZeile).Value = "Malaysia IMS CL"
      ElseIf InStr(Cx, "IMS") > 0 Then
        G.Cells(lZeile).Value = "Malaysia IMS NC"
      Else
        G.Cells(lZeile).Value = "Malaysia " & Cx & " NC"
      End If
    ElseIf InStr(Dx, "Indonesien") > 0 Then
      If InStr(Bx, "ISO 9001") > 0 Or InStr(Bx, "ISO 14001") > 0 Or InStr(Bx, "BS OHSAS 18001") > 0 Or InStr(Bx, "ISO 45001") > 0 Or InStr(Bx, "ISO 50001") > 0 Then
        G.Cells(lZeile).Value = "Indonesien IMS CL"
      ElseIf InStr(Cx, "IMS") > 0 Then
        G.Cells(lZeile).Value = "Indonesien IMS NC"
      Else
        G.Cells(lZeile).Value = "Indonesien " & Cx & " NC"
      End If
    Else
      G.Cells(lZeile).Value = ""
    End If
  Next lZeile
End Sub
```

This should both be faster and easier to read and understand.

Also check if you really need `InStr()` or if you could use `=` directly. The latter will be faster, but it will fail if the data is not clean, e.g. letter case differences, or trailing spaces.

Comment: Tomalak Wouldn't still be faster the array option? On the other hand I though `Like` is Case sensitive, but not `=`.

Comment: @Damian Strings in VB(A) are case-sensitive, so is `=`. You can do case-insensitive comparison with `StrComp()`/`InStr()` together with `vbTextCompare` though. Regarding the array, it might be faster than than calling `.Cells(x).Value` on a `Range` object, not sure. Don't have Excel right now to do any measurements, but it's worth comparing. I'd say (gut feeling) working with a cached `Range` object is pretty fast already.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thank you so much! I am really happy to meet such a great community here!

Comment: Unfortunately, I get "runtime error 13 types incompatible" when being at "Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Gesamt")"

Comment: @Sam Whoops, my bad. Updated my answer. (I don't have Excel to test this code at the moment, I'm writing this all from memory. Try to do the intended thing when you encounter an error.)